Pivoting a table using crosstab() in PostgreSQL
I've got this table in Postgres:
create table test("Product id", "Product Name", "Category", "Operator", piece)
as values
 (10,   'Carbonara',    'C1',   'User1',    1)
,(11,   'Spaghetti',    'C1',   'User2',    1)
,(12,   'Coke',         'C2',   'User1',    1)
,(10,   'Carbonara',    'C1',   'User2',    2)
,(11,   'Spaghetti',    'C1',   'User1',    1)
,(11,   'Spaghetti',    'C1',   'User3',    5)
,(12,   'Coke',         'C2',   'User3',    1)
;

I would like to have this result:



Category
User1
User 2
user 3




C1
2
3
5


C2
1
0
1



I made some test with crosstab() function, but didn't get any result.
I've tried crosstab() following some tutorial and answer here on SO, but I didn't understand very well how to create this query.

Show what you tried with crosstab, where and how it went wrong. You can also unpivot tables using conditional aggregates or an aggregate filter clause.

You can pivot tables using an aggregate filter clause. Add a coalesce() if you prefer to get a 0 when a given Operator has no rows in a given Category (all their rows would get filtered out before sum()):
demo at db<>fiddle
select "Category"
     , coalesce(sum(piece)filter(where "Operator"='User1'),0) as "User1"
     , coalesce(sum(piece)filter(where "Operator"='User2'),0) as "User2"
     , coalesce(sum(piece)filter(where "Operator"='User3'),0) as "User3"
from test
group by "Category";




Category
User1
User2
User3




C1
2
3
5


C2
1
0
1



Using crosstab():
select*from crosstab('select "Category", "Operator", sum(piece) as piece
                      from test group by 1,2 order by 1,2'
                     ,'select distinct "Operator" from test order by 1')
as ("Category" text, "User1" bigint,"User2" bigint,"User3" bigint);


thanks @Zegarek, it works flawless, tryed both method and choosed the crosstab one. thanks a lot

Alternatively you can pivot into a single JSON object instead of several (number may vary) columns.
select "Category", json_object_agg("Operator", s) users
from
(
 select "Category", "Operator", sum(piece) as s
 from test group by "Category", "Operator"
) as t
group by "Category";




Category
users




C1
{ "User2" : 3, "User3" : 5, "User1" : 2 }


C2
{ "User3" : 1, "User1" : 1 }



DB Fiddle demo

See example with crosstab.
CROSSTAB uses two subqueries.
crosstab(text source_sql, text category_sql)

Order by clause in booth subqueries is significant. Perhaps, that is whay you didn't get any result.
select *
from crosstab(
  'select "Category","Operator",sum(piece)sum_piece from test 
   group by "Category","Operator"  order by "Category","Operator"'
  ,'select distinct test."Operator" from test order by "Operator"'
  )
  as(Category text,"User1" text,"User2" text,"User3" text) 
;


Output is



category
User1
User2
User3




C1
2
3
5


C2
1
null
1



There parts of crosstab.
1.Data source  <rowid, category, value>
There column Category - rowid, Operator - category, sum(piece) - value.
More clear notation <category,attribute,value>
There column Category - category,Operator - attibute, sum(piece) - value.
select "Category","Operator",sum(piece)sum_piece 
from test 
group by "Category","Operator"
order by "Category","Operator"




Category
Operator
sum_piece




C1
User1
2


C1
User2
3


C1
User3
5


C2
User1
1


C2
User3
1




Categories <categories> (attributes).

select distinct "Operator" from test order by "Operator"




Operator




User2


User1


User3



fiddle

Follow this query:
SELECT 
    "Category",
    SUM(CASE WHEN "Operator" = 'User1' THEN piece ELSE 0 END) AS User1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN "Operator" = 'User2' THEN piece ELSE 0 END) AS User2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN "Operator" = 'User3' THEN piece ELSE 0 END) AS User3
FROM test
GROUP BY "Category"
ORDER BY "Category";

Output:

